# htaccess URL rewriting max parameter length

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm building a mini framework that supports:

```
mysite.com/template/
mysite.com/template/action/
mysite.com/template/action/model/
```

Using as a bootstrap:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

But for any request:

```
mysite.com/template/action/model/**extra/stuff/should/vanish/**
```

So that the maximum URL size will always drop anything extra:

```
mysite.com/template/action/model/
```

Comment: I have no precise answer to your question, but please read about [DPI] Apache's flag, as it may become useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do mean something like this?

```
# if more than 3 nodes deep          v--- the extra stuff should vanish
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.+ /$1/$2/$3/? [R=301,L]
```

This redirects the browser so that it only preserves the 3 nodes if there are more than 3. This should probably go above your routing rules.

---

EDIT:

> becuase on the forth block this case doesnt hold up: site.com/a/b/c/?d

You'll need a specific rule to match against the query string here, it's beyond what you can do in the expression of a `RewriteRule`. You can put these rules either before or after the above one:

```
# Check if there's a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
# if there are exactly 3 nodes, then remove the query string
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3/? [R=301,L]
```

The query string (everything after the **`?`**) isn't part of the URI that is used in the rewrite engine, it requires a special condition.

Comment: @DanKanze The very last `/` in the `/$1/$2/$3/?` is optional. I had put it there because it was included in one of your examples.

Comment: no not in the htaccess file i mean when a user passes parameter in URL

Comment: becuase on the forth block this case doesnt hold up: site.com/a/b/c/?d

Comment: @DanKanze No, the rule won't apply to that, the `RewriteRule `expression cannot match against the query string (everything after the **`?**` in the URL), for that, you'd need a completely different rule specifically to match that. Please see the edit